# Переборка двух массивов и замена значений

Tags: php, циклы

Здравствуйте.
Есть два массива вида:

Первый:

```
$arr = array(
"null" => "0",
"one" => "0",
"two" => "0",
.....
);
```

Второй:

```
$arr2 = array();
$arr2[]=array("block"=>"null", "value"=>"some");
$arr2[]=array("block"=>"one","value"=>"var");
...
$arr[]=array("block"=>"etc","value"=>"etc");
```

Нужно как-то перебрать эти два массива, чтобы были присвоены значения из второго массива первому.
Т.е. `$arr['null']` стало равно `$arr[0]['value']`
И так со всеми элементами массива.
С замечательным `foreach` я так и не подружился, поэтому прошу помощи у Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарно;)

```
foreach ($arr2 as $item)
{
    $arr[$item['block']] = $item['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите слить 2 массива, подойдёт функция **array_merge**
[PHP.SU / array_merge](http://www.php.su/functions/?array-merge)

**foreach**, простой пример:

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'Andrey',
    'email' => 'example@mail.com',
    'birthdate' => '1991-12-11'
);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: {$key} => Value: {$value}<br>";
}
```

На выходе:

```
Key: name => Value: Andrey
Key: email => Value: example@mail.com
Key: birthdate => Value: 1991-12-11
```